# Using str_extract_all to extract publications from specific portal out of hundreds of portals in a string.

Tags: r, regex, sorting, rvest

Using a simple code to extract the links to my articles (one by one)

```
library(rvest) 
url = ("http://www.time.mk/week/2016/22")
frontpage = read_html(url) %>%
html_nodes(".other_articles") %>%
html_attr("href") %>%
paste0()
print(frontpage)
mark = "http://www dot time dot mk/"
frontpagelinks = paste0(mark, frontpage)
final = list()
final = read_html(frontpagelinks[1]) %>%
html_nodes("h1 a") %>%
html_attr("href")%>%
paste0()
```

I used 
    `a1onJune = str_extract_all(frontpage, ".*a1on.*")` to extract articles from the website a1on dot mk, which worked like a charm finding only the articles I needed.

After getting some help here as to how to make my code more efficient, i.e. extract numerous links at once, via:

```
linksList <- lapply(frontpagelinks, function(i) {
read_html(frontapagelinks[i]) %>%
html_nodes("h1 a") %>%
html_attr("href")%>%
paste0()
```

which extracts all of the links I need, the same stringr code returns oddly enough something like this

"\"standard dot mk/germancite-ermenskiot-genocid/\", \"//plusinfo dot mk/vest/72702/turcija-ne-go-prifakja-zborot-genocid\", **\"/a1on dot mk/wordpress/archives/618719\",** \"sitel dot mk/na-povidok-nov-sudir-megju-turcija-i-germanija\",

Where as shown in bold I also extract the links to the website I need, but also a bunch of other noise that I definitely don't want there. I tried a variety of regex expressions, however I've not managed to define only those lines of code that contain a1on posts.

Given that the list which I am attempting to clear out outputs separated links I am a bit baffled by the fact that when I use stringr it (as far as im concerned) randomly divides them into strings of multiple links:

[93] "http://telegraf dot mk /aktuelno/svet/ns-newsarticle-vo-znak-na-protest-turcija-go-povlece-svojot-ambasador-od-germanija.nspx"
 [94] "http://tocka dot mk /1/197933/odnosite-pomegju-berlin-i-ankara-pred-totalen-kolaps-germanija-go-prizna-turskiot-genocid-nad-ermencite"
 [95] "lokalno dot mk /merkel-vladata-na-germanija-e-podgotvena-da-pomogne-vo-dijalogot-megju-turcija-i-ermenija/"

Any thoughts as to how I can go about this? Perhaps something that is more general, given that I need to do the same type of cleaning for five different portals.

Thank you.

Comment: It's kind of tough to fully understand your question.  You might want to try `frontpage[grepl(".*a1on.*", frontpage)]` instead of `str_extract_all(frontpage, ".*a1on.*")`.

Comment: Yes, sorry about not making it completely clear! But what you said combined with epi 99's unlist response, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

```
Using a simple code to extract the links to my articles (one by one)

library(rvest) 
url = ("http://www.time.mk/week/2016/22")
frontpage = read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes(".other_articles") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>%
  paste0()
print(frontpage)
mark = "http://www.time.mk/"
frontpagelinks = paste0(mark, frontpage)

# lappy returns a list of lists, so use unlist to flatten
linksList <- unlist( lapply(frontpagelinks, function(i) {
  read_html(i) %>%
    html_nodes("h1 a") %>%
    html_attr("href") %>%
    paste0()}))

# grab the lists of interest
a1onLinks <- linksList[grepl(".*a1on.*", linksList)]

# [1] "http://a1on.mk/wordpress/archives/621196" "http://a1on.mk/wordpress/archives/621038"
# [3] "http://a1on.mk/wordpress/archives/620576" "http://a1on.mk/wordpress/archives/620686"
# [5] "http://a1on.mk/wordpress/archives/620364" "http://a1on.mk/wordpress/archives/620399"
```